# Know original user id from the sudo users activity

Tags: linux, sudo, users

Suppose i am a user of linux box : A
I also have an access to application account in the box and I `sudo` it : B
Somebody else who is a user C also `sudo` to: B

**Question**: When the user C copies or modifies any file say test.txt in a folder say /home/application/ , I need to know who has done it means the original id (C).

When I execute `ls -ltr` it shows that the file is created and modified by application account "B". I wanted to know the real user , in this case it wold be "C"

Is there any possibility to know it?

Comment: You will have to look at the logs.

Answer (score -1):

> stat

command shows necessary details

Or you can write this command.

> grep -H filename /home/*/.bash_history

Comment: stat will show B, not C.